# Grails 2.3.4: test-app on new app fails with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsEclipseConsole"

Tags: grails, classnotfoundexception

The test-app command run with the below errors...

I'm execute the Grails on the Windows platform, the following `recomended solutions` ( that I found...  ) doesn't help.

```
1. grails clean ; grails compile --refresh-dependencies 
2. Deleted he data from .grails directory
```

Environment Variables JAVA_PATH,GRAILS_PATH, PATH defined properly.

Someone have idea how to fix this problem?

```
Loading Grails 2.3.4

|Configuring classpath

.
|Environment set to test

......................................

|Running without daemon...

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.ide.eclipse.runtime.GrailsEclipseConsole
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.createInstance(GrailsConsole.java:282)
    at grails.build.logging.GrailsConsole.getInstance(GrailsConsole.java:246)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1725)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3461)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.DependencyManagerConfigurer.configureIvy(DependencyManagerConfigurer.groovy:126)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1281)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.postLoadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1219)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1115)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1087)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1073)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1053)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProcess.initializeBuildSettings(ForkedGrailsProcess.groovy:736)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.initializeProjectInstance(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:73)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:76)
```